# Automatic build with Add from URL

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do a auto build on hub.docker.com using a ADD with files from a URL.  I have the following docker file on github, builds are being triggered:

```html
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Andy Cobley "andy@example.org"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-29-04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
ADD http://example.org:8080/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD http://example.org:8080/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

The files are not being added into the container.  I can confirm the files do exist on the server and are accessible.  Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Do you get an error message during the `docker build`?

Comment: It's generally better to do a `RUN curl...` for this sort of stuff; you can then compose it with other commands to avoid using up layers and it will get cached (which may or may not be a good thing).

Comment: No errors during the build.  Adrian, curl sounds like a good option

Comment: If it works locally, it's possible automated builds are placing a restriction on ADD commands.

Comment: Looking at this further, it seems this may not be a dockerhub/docker problem.  The fault above was reported using a azure ubuntu server.  Using boot2docker on a mac does work.

Answer (score 0):

As your first ADD ends with a /, docker thinks the source (global.conf) is a directory, try with `ADD http://example.org:8080/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/global.conf`

Comment: Not sure thats the problem,if I build by hand locally, even with remote URL's it seems to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this.  building remotely in this situation you need to do a docker pull before doing a docker run.